# Filling area between two lines and an arc

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I have the following diagram I would like to convert (approximately) to tikz:

[image]

So far, I've succeeded at doing everything except the shading. I am a newbie to tikz and learning the best I can so please bear with me - horrible code patched up from various tutorials ahead:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{mark coordinate}=[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0,outer
 sep=0,fill=none,circle]

\coordinate[mark coordinate] (M) at ( 0,0); 
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (L) at (-4,0);
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (R) at ( 4,0);
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (N) at ( 0,4);

% Horizontal axis (surface)
\draw[solid] (L) to (R);

% Normal vector (+ label)
\draw [ultra thick,-latex,black] (M) to (N);
\node[anchor=west] (note1) at (-0.5,3.5) {$\mathbf{n}$};

 % Draw arc
 \coordinate[mark coordinate] (P) at (-4,0);
 \coordinate[mark coordinate] (Phat) at (4,0);
 \draw[solid] let \p1=(P), \p2=(Phat), \n0={0.5*veclen(\x1-\x2,\y1-
 \y2)} in
 [rotate={atan((\y1-\y2)/(\x1-\x2))}] (P) arc (180:0:\n0);

% The area delimiters
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (left) at (-0.5,0);
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (right) at (0.5,0);

% The two destination point pairs
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (left_d) at (3.696844, 1.527526);
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (right_d) at (3.813822, 1.206132);

\coordinate[mark coordinate] (left2_d) at (-2.363246, 3.227237);
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (right2_d) at (-1.613246, 3.660250);

% The parallel lines
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\draw[red] (left) to (left_d);
\draw[red] (right) to (right_d);
\draw[darkgreen] (left) to (left2_d);
\draw[darkgreen] (right) to (right2_d);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result is this:

[image]

I am unsure how to get the shading working - I have looked around but I only see examples on how to shade the area between two or more curves, however I am not using curves but geometric objects. How would I go about achieving this? And if my original code can be rewritten more elegantly to simplify shading, please go ahead!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Method 1: Approx Solution: Rectangular Fill

You can apply a `fill` to a path consisting of the four corners that you want to fill:

```
\fill [fill=green!25] (left) -- (left2_d) -- (right2_d) -- (right) -- cycle;

\fill [fill=red!25] (left) -- (left_d) -- (right_d) -- (right) -- (left) -- cycle;
```

This yields what looks like the desired results, but does not curve along the arc.

### Method 2: Circular Fill

Instead of a rectangular fill, you could actually define the curve along the path which will certainly yield the correct results, but I think an easier method would be to use a `\clip` instead.

### Method 3: Clip

I would recommend that you over `fill` the area, and `clip` it to the desired region.
Easiest way to over fill the area is to extend the vectors from near the origin to the circular edge using a syntax such as `($(left)!1.1!(left2_d)$)` to locate the point 10% past the circular arc. So before we apply the `\clip` the fill region looks like:

[image]

By adding `\clip  (P) arc (180:0:4) -- (Phat) -- cycle` we limit all the drawing to be within the desired region and achieve:

[image]

I also placed the portions that needed clipping within a `scope` so that the clip does not affect the lines that are drawn on top of the clip path.  Comment out the `\begin{scope} and` \end{scope}` to see what I mean.

### Notes:

- Using `mark coordinate` on a `\coordinate` does not make sense as `\coordinate` does not do any drawing, just locates a coordinate, so I have removed that.
- Also, I rearranged the order of the drawing to show the things I think you wanted to be on top. An alternate way would be to use layers, but simply rearranging the drawing order suffices for many uses.
- Nodes can be placed at the end of the path -- this is usually an easier option than placing the label manually based on coordinates. I adjust the placement of the `n` label yo illustrate this.
- I am not sure exactly why this was necessary, but the horizontal line needed a tweak of `0.5\pgflinewidth` on either end to get the edges to meet properly.

---

As far as your other request to bend the colors over the shaded region you could use opacity as  Lionel MANSUY suggested, but I find it clearer if you combine opacity with some sort of pattern, which requires `\usetikzlibrary{patterns}`:

```
\fill [fill=green, pattern=crosshatch dots] 
    (left) -- ($(left)!1.1!(left2_d)$) -- 
    ($(right)!1.1!(right2_d)$) -- (right) -- cycle;

\fill [draw=none, fill=red!50, fill opacity=0.25] 
    (left) -- ($(left)!1.1!(left_d)$) -- 
    ($(right)!1.1!(right_d)$) -- (right)  -- cycle;
```

which yields:

[image]

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\tikzstyle{mark coordinate}=[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0,outer
% sep=0,fill=none,circle]

\coordinate (M) at ( 0,0); 
\coordinate (L) at (-4,0);
\coordinate (R) at ( 4,0);
\coordinate (N) at ( 0,4);

% The area delimiters
\coordinate (left) at (-0.5,0);
\coordinate (right) at (0.5,0);

% The two destination point pairs
\coordinate (left_d) at (3.696844, 1.527526);
\coordinate (right_d) at (3.813822, 1.206132);

\coordinate (left2_d) at (-2.363246, 3.227237);
\coordinate (right2_d) at (-1.613246, 3.660250);


 % Draw arc
 \coordinate (P)    at (-4,0);
 \coordinate (Phat) at (4,0);
 \begin{scope}
    \clip  (P) arc (180:0:4) -- (Phat) -- cycle;


    \fill [fill=green!25] 
        (left) -- 
        ($(left)!1.1!(left2_d)$) -- 
        ($(right)!1.1!(right2_d)$) -- 
        (right) --
        cycle;
    
    \fill [draw=none, fill=red!25] 
        (left) -- 
        ($(left)!1.1!(left_d)$) -- 
        ($(right)!1.1!(right_d)$) --
        (right)   -- 
        (left) -- cycle;
 \end{scope}

 \draw [solid, ultra thick] 
        let \p1=(P), 
            \p2=(Phat), 
            \n0={0.5*veclen(\x1-\x2,\y1-\y2)} 
        in [rotate={atan((\y1-\y2)/(\x1-\x2))}] (P) arc (180:0:\n0);

% The parallel lines
 \definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
 \draw[red] (left) to (left_d);
 \draw[red] (right) to (right_d);
 \draw[darkgreen] (left) to (left2_d);
 \draw[darkgreen] (right) to (right2_d);

% Horizontal axis (surface)
 \draw[solid, ultra thick] ($(L)-(0.5\pgflinewidth,0)$) -- 
    ($(R)+(0.5\pgflinewidth,0)$);

% Normal vector (+ label)
%\draw [ultra thick,-latex,black] (M) to (N);
%\node[anchor=west] (note1) at (-0.5,3.5) {$\mathbf{n}$};
\draw [ultra thick,-latex,black] (M) to (N) 
    node [below left, yshift=-7] {$\mathbf{n}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, \fill is very nice! This still misses the subtended arc but I think I can get that part on my own now that I understand the method. Thanks! Is there a way to blend the two shades at the bottom or is tikz not designed that way? (I could fill that triangle separately but just wondering)

Comment: @Thomas: Sorry had a phone call, updated solution should be ready in about 10 minutes.

Comment: @Thomas To blend the two shades at the bottom, you could either determine the intersection point and redraw/refill the surface with an appropriate color, or use transparency (see command `\pgfsetfillopacity` in the Tikz manual)