# TikZ: how to fill area defined by intersections?

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, fill

I would like to fill this triangle-like
[image]

The code is:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % \draw [help lines] (7,0) grid (11,4);
    \draw [fill=red] (0,1.3) circle (1.3); 
    \draw [fill=blue] plot [smooth cycle,scale=0.4, xshift=18cm, yshift=1.5cm] coordinates
    {(1,0) (0,2) (1.3,4) (3.6,2) (3.6+3.6-1.3,4) (2*3.6,2) (3.6+3.6-1,0) (3.6,1)}; 
    \draw (8.55,0.98) -- ++ (0.1,-1.47) (8.7,0.99) -- (8.55+0.1,-0.49); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have looked up on [Filling area between two lines and an arc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84738/filling-area-between-two-lines-and-an-arc) but I could not find a solution. I think that first I should give the name to the blue object through `name path=candy`. Then, I should give the command

```
\path[name path=twolines] (0.98) -- ++ (0.1,-1.47) (8.7,0.99) -- (8.55+0.1,-0.49);
```

to find the intersections. After that, with the command `fill`, I should be able to fill that area. The problem is that I do not know how. Maybe with the aid of `\clip`, but again, how?

Comment: If you can use one of the answers, then please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two simple tricks can save you a tone of work. Draw that triangle and fill it as usual `[fill=<color>]` before drawing that moth shape, then shift the triangle upward a very small length to hide that tiny white space between the arc and the triangle side. Finally draw the curvy shape. It's a bit of an approximation but will save you much headache.

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % \draw [help lines] (7,0) grid (11,4);
    \draw [fill=red] (0,1.3) circle (1.3);
    \draw [fill=red,yshift=1pt] (8.55,0.98) -- ++(0.1,-1.47) -- (8.7,0.99); 
    \draw [fill=blue] plot [smooth cycle,scale=0.4, xshift=18cm, yshift=1.5cm] coordinates
    {(1,0) (0,2) (1.3,4) (3.6,2) (3.6+3.6-1.3,4) (2*3.6,2) (3.6+3.6-1,0) (3.6,1)}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply draw your triangle a little too large in the top - I use the `shorten`option with a negative length. -and then place your bow on top of it for a perfect result like this:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw [fill=red, shorten <=-0.1cm, shorten >=-0.1cm] (8.55,0.98) -- (8.65,-0.49) -- (8.7,0.99); 
   \draw [fill=blue] plot [smooth cycle,scale=0.4, xshift=18cm, yshift=1.5cm] coordinates
    {(1,0) (0,2) (1.3,4) (3.6,2) (3.6+3.6-1.3,4) (2*3.6,2) (3.6+3.6-1,0) (3.6,1)}; 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Filled triangle with bow]

If you for some reason need a perfect filled triangle in the foreground, then you can use the inverted clip from @Jake's answer with the bow: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12033/8650